# There's no grammar rule to support that it's correct to use 'would' to talk about possible future outcomes, so why do native speakers do that?

Tags: grammar

"Cancelling the HS2 high-speed rail project would risk a nationwide economic catastrophe."
Source: theindependent.co.uk

Based on what I have read about "would" in more than six reliable dictionaries, it cannot be used to talk about future possibilities, which have some chance of happening. Only 'will', 'can', 'could', 'may', and 'might' can be used for that.

Yet it's very common for native speakers to use "would" to talk about possibilities.

Comment: Your example is interpreted as having a conditional meaning. The use of preterite "would" marks it as a 'remote' conditional.  The 'open' conditional version uses present tense "will": _Cancelling the HS2 high-speed rail project will risk a nationwide economic catastrophe_.

Comment: The implied meaning is "If the HS2 project were to be cancelled, this would risk an economic catastrophe."

Comment: @onose shaibu I see you posted the same question on at least one other website under the name of _hardyweineberg_. Multiple postings of the same question on different websites may deter members here from answering your question.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include a few of the actual citations behind your statement that at least six dictionaries say you can't use *would* for future possibilities? I ask you to do so because in the sentence *“I didn't think it **would** be cancelled”*, you can plainly see *would* being used for a future possibility.  (That sentence is merely the past tense of *“I don't think it **will** be cancelled.”*) So I imagine you've accidentally left out some essential context that would make whatever you read reasonable. Right now, it seems clearly incorrect as you have rendered it.

Comment: Well, that's a good reason not to look for grammatical information in dictionaries (especially online dictionaries, which are full of nonsense). How do you know theres no grammar rule that supports it? And if you keep hearing native speakers say it, go ahead and say it too, and quit trying to tell them what's correct.

Comment: @JohnLawler please, tell me sites that I can check for grammar rules.

Comment: [You can start here](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/Preliminarybufattenedlistoftransformations.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

> *Cancelling the HS2 high-speed rail project would risk a nationwide*
> *economic catastrophe.*

This has a conditional interpretation similar to "If the HS2 high-speed rail project was cancelled it would risk a nationwide economic catastrophe", where preterite "would" in the apodosis marks it as a 'remote' conditional.

The 'open' conditional version, by contrast, uses present tense "will": "Cancelling the HS2 high-speed rail project will risk a nationwide economic catastrophe."

Comment: Can your translate 'preterite "would" in the apodosis' into language to be understood by a learner of English, please.

Comment: Preterite = past tense. The apodosis is the clause that expresses the outcome of the condition being fulfilled.